# How to pipe a single item from a command output into another command?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, xargs

Basic example using grep (note that grep would not be my only use-case for this):

```
$ grep -Irl "foo"
path/to/directory/help.js
path/to/directory/config.js
path/to/directory/task.js
```

Now I want to open the `config.js` file in Vi. My normal method would be:

```
$ vi path/to/directory/config.js
```

which I had to either type by hand with the assistance of tab-completion, or I highlighted the filename from the grep result and copy/pasted it.

But I'd like to be able to Vi the file by just specifying that it was the 2nd result in the grep command. So something like:

```
$ grep -Irl "foo" | xargs vi 2
```

Obviously xargs would not work like that, was just an example. But I'm trying to find if there's a way using xargs (or any other utility) to accomplish this and I'm not finding it.

Something that a teammate suggested to me was to use `head` and `tail` together, like this:

```
$ grep -Irl "foo" | tail -n 1 | xargs vi
```

would retrieve task.js, and

```
$ grep -Irl "foo" | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | xargs vi
```

would retrieve config.js. Wondering if there is a less verbose method.

Comment: Selecting by line number seems like a strange thing to do. How do you know the line number if you haven't first displayed the output on the terminal? And then you have to count lines to figure out which you want. Why not `grep -Irl "foo" path | grep config`?

Comment: It's unlikely that I know that `config.js` exists before doing this, so first I'd just perform the grep. Then when I see a file I want to do something to, I'd hit the up-arrow to run the grep again and pipe the result to something that would open the file I want. The goal is to avoid using my mouse to copy/paste a file path. A co-worker showed me I can also use `screen` to select text anywhere on the screen using a keyboard. I realize this might not save a lot of time, especially if the lines are too many to count and now I'm having to display line numbers in my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
   vi $( grep -IrL "foo" | awk "NR==3" )
```

This uses AWK to find the appropriate line.  The output is then used as a command line argument for vi.

I'm oldschool, so I prefer the equivalent, but slightly frowned upon version-

```
 vi ` grep -IrL "foo" | awk "NR==3" `
```

Comment: Why is the backtick version more frowned upon? One less keystroke for my purposes...

Comment: Have a read of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated#126928  (and don't forget to upvote my answer if you like it !)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what was asked for because it doesn't use a pipeline into vi, but using [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29878/can-i-access-nth-line-number-of-standard-output):

`vi $( grep -Irl "foo" | sed -n '2 p')`

Comment: Nothing to stop this being done by piping into vi - grep -Irl "foo" | sed -n '2 p' | xargs vi

Comment: Now I have to vote between using sed vs. awk. Seems like awk is generally favored as it can do everything sed can do plus more? I also prefer the awk method syntactically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk

Answer (score 1):

I have written a wrapper function for this purpose, which you can use if you want to reuse an output line from a command.

First the function for *bash*:

```
catch() {
   out="$($@)" 
   nl <<< "$out"
   read -a r -d '\n' <<< "$out"
   r=("dummy" "${r[@]}")
}
```

Then for *zsh*:

```
catch () {
   out="$($@)" 
   nl <<< "$out"
   r=("${(@f)out}") 
}
```

The usage is for both variants the same. First, do a run of the desired command, prepended with *catch*, which will present you the command's output with a nice numbering:

```
$ catch grep -Irl "foo"
   1  path/to/dir/task.js
   2  path/to/dir/help.js
   3  path/to/dir/config.js
$
```

Now, you can reuse any line in a following command by using the array parameter `$r`, e.g.

```
$ wc -c ${r[2]}
14044 path/to/dir/help.js
```

In *zsh* you can omit the curly brackets (`wc -c $r[2]`) but in *bash* you need them unfortunately.

Some caveats which come to my mind:

- the output is only displayed after the command has finished
- strange charactes in output might produce erratic behaviour (e.g. newlines in filename)
- only output to STDOUT is captured (if some output is written to STDERR, it'll get unmixed on the console and ignored in `$r`)